# Me sale esta error "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java

```java
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();        
        fileChooser.setTitle("Seleccionar Archivos PDF");      
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("archivos PDF", "*.pdf"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        
        List<File> listFile = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
        ArrayList<Paciente> listDatos = new ArrayList();
        
        if (listFile != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.size(); i++) {
                String NombreArchivo = listFile.get(i).getPath();
                PDDocument pdDocument = null;
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(NombreArchivo);

                try {

                    pdDocument = Loader.loadPDF(new File(NombreArchivo));//obtenemos la direccion del archivo en nombreArchivo

                    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();//
                    pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
                    pdfStripper.setEndPage(1);
                    String texto = pdfStripper.getText(pdDocument);

                    //System.out.println("******************" + listFile.get(i) + "******");
                    //System.out.println(texto);                   
                    String[] dividido = texto.split("\\R");

                    for (int j = 40; j < dividido.length; j++) {
                        extraerdatos(dividido[j]);

                    }
                    pdDocument.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("no Selecciono archivos");

        }
        
    }
```

Me sale el error en el "stage" y de ahi no pasa tenia el código en `javafx 8` pero cambie el proyecto por java

Comment: Hola @Marcos S, cambiar de javaFx a java, es como cambiar de python a java, hay cosas que van a funcionar, y muchas que no, en java no hay **Stage**, de ahgí tu falla, en algunos aspectos (la interfaz grafica sobre todo), es casi como crear un programa nuevo, te sugiero que evalúes que tan costoso y necesario es realizar la migración.

Comment: Puede añadir los import de esa clase .creo que es un error al importar una clase awt en vez de javafx